# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Using Angular 2.4.0 (current setup with Angular CLI v1.0.0-rc.0)
Created components, classes and services, default specs created.  ng test worked fine.

Added an input with [(ngModel)] in it, and now am getting the message above when I run "ng test"

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AbsenceComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

absence.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-absence',
  templateUrl: './absence.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./absence.component.css']
})
export class AbsenceComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedValue = null;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

absence.component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option value="0">Value 0</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

absence.component.spec.ts (default created by "ng g component absence")

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AbsenceComponent } from './absence.component';

describe('AbsenceComponent', () => {
  let component: AbsenceComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AbsenceComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AbsenceComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AbsenceComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't see any issue with your code, Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KUFvkEc3cg6PR9dshbjQ?p=preview), Can you update it to replicate issue?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan, the issue comes when you run ng test

Comment: Can you show how does your TestBed Configuration looks like?

Comment: `... getting the message above when I run "ng test"` <= yet you did not include any of that code. Maybe someone will venture a lucky guess, if you want an answer though please update your question with your test code.

Comment: @Igor, added.  It is just the default spec that is created by ng g component

Comment: FYI, everything else in this application is as it is defaulted from ng new

Comment: @BillF, you need to import  `imports:      [ FormsModule ]` in your configureTestingModule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below,

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],  
     // you need to import, provide anything you need in the component 
     // so that they can be used\injected in the component for test.
      declarations: [ AbsenceComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#import-module).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thank you.  I'm just getting started on this whole karma-jasmine testing framework, and it can be daunting.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about declaring modules in the test as well as in the module.ts